# why category__and and category__in wont work togather?

Tags: categories

I am having an issue here. I want to get all the post that are related to the current post at the same time it will also have a common category term.

for example:

Post XYZ has categories car, Truck, and Bus.

So i want to get any posts that have car or truck or bus at the same time it will also have category "Toronto"

What would be the query?

Comment: have a look at [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) for complex taxonomy queries.

Comment: @Milo Perfect Solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a query like this -

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'car', 'truck', 'bus' ),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => 'Toronto'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Just a question. Why field => 'slug' and field => 'name' ? Both are taxonomy "category".

Comment: If the slug for `"Toronto"` is `"toronto"`, then you can use edit the second tax_query argument, and set `'field' => 'slug'` and `'terms' => 'toronto'`. I have separated `tax_query` into two items to support your requirements. First arguments says, it will need to be from any of the category `car or truck or bus`, second argument says, it will need to be from `toronto`, and the total tax query says, it will need to match both conditions `AND`